# Are objects initialised to nil by default in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, object, initialization

```
NSArray *items;
NSArray *items = nil;
```

Is there any difference in these two statements in Objective-C?

Comment: This might help you to understand `If an object does not implement an initializer, Cocoa invokes the initializer of the nearest ancestor instead.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects are initialized [to zero or nil](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ObjectAllocation/ObjectAllocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH7-SW1) before the initializer runs.

Then check [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html) for more info:

> It isn’t necessary to initialize all instance variables of an object explicitly, just those that are necessary to make the object functional. The default set-to-zero initialization performed on an instance variable during allocation is often sufficient. Make sure that you retain or copy instance variables, as required for memory management.

Comment: The OP is talking about the object *pointers*, not the memory occupied by the objects themselves.

Comment: Check the other link and quote

Comment: Now you are referring to instance variables when the OP is clearly referring to local or global variables.

Comment: Your answer should be in your answer--not in a link.